# Oauth Implicit Grant web api authorization server

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api, oauth, authorization, owin

I am looking at the following example for the implicit grant.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/OWIN-OAuth-20-Authorization-ba2b8783

I can see how the example is redirecting unauthenticated user to the same authorization serer's log in page. which is something like follows:

```
Client ---> AuthServer ---> 401
                             |
       <--- Login (UI) <------
            (On Auth server)
```

My problem is that I dont want to authorization server to handle UI part of login page. That is my authorization server is a web api and its only job is to process the owin pipeline and authenticate user via webapi.

So ideally what I would like to do is, that authorization server respond with 401 to the client. Client (could pure js app) show login page (username/password) and POST to authorization server with username/password over SSL and auth. server says you are ok to login.

This will give all the client to manage Look and feel of their login page but the authentication (logic) part is done via auth server webapi.

Is this possible?
Are there any security implication that I need to be aware of when implementing this (only specific to this scenario) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the implementation of the authorization server supports "[Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3)" and allows your application to use it, you can implement your scenario. However, it is unlikely that the authorization server does.

The primary purpose of OAuth 2.0 is to allow third-party applications (like your application) to access protected resources of end users (= resource owners) **without passing end users' credentials (username/password) to the third-party applications**. So, your scenario is the very use case that OAuth 2.0 tries to avoid.

---

[Comment to your additional question]

If you are an implementor of an authorization server, yes, you can implement both "Implicit Grant" and "Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant". It's up to you. On the other hand, if you are an implementor of a client application which accesses an authorization server that has been implemented by someone else (at least not by you), whether your client application can use "Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant" depends on the implementation of the authorization server. What I meant was that in general authorization server implementations would not give a chance for third-party applications to use "Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant", because it's a kind of the last resort and the specification (RFC 6749) says *"The authorization server should take special care when enabling this grant type and **only allow it when other flows are not viable**."*

Comment: Hi, I understand what you saying here that yes its possible but its anti-pattern from oauth point of view. What do you mean by "However, it is unlikely that the authorization server does.". I have implemented both "Implicit Grant" and "Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant" on auth server. Are you saying it should only have one?

Comment: See my comment added to the answer.